# jquery lost events

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, jquery

I would like to know if is there some jquery known behaviour that cause the lost of events handlers (in particular in iframes)?

I've a strange kind of problem. 
I've built a webapp composed of two iframe.
First i load content in the first iframe. I add some event event handler using jquery to first iframe content dom. 
Everything works. 
On user input i load a page in the second iframe. Here too, I add some event handlers using jquery.
Then the strange thing happens: jquery lost the event handlers in the first iframe.
I said 'jquery lost' because if I add an event listener old way, it is still present.

Comment: do they ever work in the first iframe? it could be a same-domain problem.

Comment: they work in the first I frame until i load something in the second.
The page containing the ifrrames and the pages loaded in the iframes are on same domain. 
The event handlers are bound from the child page, not from the 'father'

Comment: wow, that last part is really interesting. is jQuery the only thing running? if it is, and you can consistently reproduce it, make a sample page and submit a bug. that's assuming no one else can think of a good reason for it to be happening.

Comment: jQuery is the only lib running. I can try to reproduce the problem, but i think it will be hard. The webapp is run in an embedded browser (has been told to me that is an opera for mips).
I'm not having tha same problem on firefox.
I think it could be something related to the execution time of some operation since the device where the opera is running is way slower than a pc. Could be that I do someting that in ordinary browser is overridden by following actions, but in slower device it is run after overriding actions.
The hard part is discovering which is the operation that cause the 'freeze'

Comment: Cross-window scripting is full of subtle and nasty little race conditions (and sometimes browser bugs). I don't think we'll be able to get much further without a test case.

Comment: i just debugged a little more and discovered that the problem raise when accessing iframe2.contentWindow or iframe2.contentDocument in the load event of he the second iframe (iframe2).

I'll try to access the contentWindow outside the load event.

Another interesting thing: seems this problem occour only when the second iframe is statically present in html, not when dinamically created and added to dom.

I will debug little further and post here the discovering.

By the way, anyone now how does jquery stores the event handlers for custom events?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

The problem was caused accessing `iframe2.contentWindow` or `iframe2.contentDocument` on the second iframe, when the src of the second iframe was changed (1st time everything worked, from the 2nd onward caused problems) and the second frame was statically coded in the html.

To solve the problem I always remove the second iframe and recreate and append it to dom dynamically via javascript.

The problem occurs only on opera 9.7 embedded for mips (not sure for the exact version)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) to bind events. This way when you add new elements with the same selector it will have the event binded to them.

```
$("p").live("click", function(){
    $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
});
```

Every subsequent p that is added to the page will have the event **binded** too.

Comment: unfortunaly, I've a quite complex webapp in first i frame, replacing all bind function with live could be difficult and somewhere not possible. Plus, I don't add content to the dom of first iframe.